# jspのiteratorについて

Tags: java, jsp, struts

jspでiteratorを使ってセッションを値を取得したいんですが、

```
<s:form action="hogeAction" >  //hogeActionに送る
<s:iterator value="session.data">　//session.dataに入ってるデータをiteratorで 
取得している
<s:property value="name" />　//session.dataの中のname
<s:property value="id" />　　//session.dataの中のid

<input type="hidden" name="item" value=' <s:property value="name" />’>
//↑ここでもsession.dataの中のnameを取得したいんだが、なぜか入っては、いるものの 
nameの値全部が入っている。 
</s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

inputの前でもiteratorしましたが思うように行かず、、、
iteratorで取り出せるのは一回までなんですかね？？？

追記:
session.dataのnameの値はapple,orange,peachが配列の中に入っており、イテレータを使ってJSPに一つずつ表示させます。クリックしたら買い物カゴにぶち込むという機能をつけるべく、formの中にdivタグでその中にそれぞれデータを入れます。クリックしたやつだけデータを送り、買い物カゴに入れたいんです。formで送る値はinputの中に書かなければいけないらしく、hidden属性にしました。んでクリックして確認のために表示させてみるとappleのところをクリックしたのに配列全部の値を取得してしまいました。なぜかtypeをcheckboxにしてみるとチェックしたやつだけ表示できました。が、そのdivタグ内に写真やら説明文やらを追加する予定でそれらどれでもいいのでクリックしたら買い物カゴに追加したいのでcheckboxだと、うーんという感じです。モヤモヤを消したいです。

Comment: 他の質問もそうでしたが、タグの開始と終了の対応関係が取れていないようなコードになっています。質問をする前に載せるコードをよく見直して下さい。

Comment: 修正しました。すいませんがおねがいします。

Comment: 想定していた結果と実際の結果（出力されたHTMLのソースコード）を追記していただけますか？

Comment: 追記しますた。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！グーグルさんに聞いたところよくわかりませんでした。もしやthi sという仕組みですか？thisって HTMLでも組めるんですかね。

Comment: うぉぉ！ありがとうございます！今から読みますね。ちなみになんてグーグル先生に聞きましたか？？英語のサイトってなんだか避けちゃうんですよなぁ。ちゃんと読まなきゃいけませんね泣

Comment: `"onclick" "s:property " "s:iterator"`です。

Answer (score 1):

今のコードからは、`name`属性が同じ3つの`input`タグが出力されるので（以下）、リクエストパラメータ`item`の値はapple,orange,peachの3つになります。

```
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="apple" />
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="orange" />
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="peach" />
```

クリックしたものだけデータを送りたいのであれば、それを識別できる簡単な仕組みを実装する必要があります。それに関してはググって調べて下さい。

**追記**

> ありがとうございます！グーグルさんに聞いたところよくわかりませんでした。

ググって最初に以下の記事が出てきました。参考になると思います。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020727/how-to-submit-specific-iterator-entry-to-action-in-struts-2